# Google maps api marker info in sidebar

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm currently creating an interactive web map using Google Maps Javascript API version 3.  I'm not sure if this is possible but I would like to create a series of map layers consisting of different kml files that could be toggled from the side bar.  I would also like to be able to access the individual points within the kmls so that when the user clicks on a particular point, photos, text etc. can be loaded outside the map window...

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I've been searching for a while and only found ways of configuring the infowindow which I personally find unattractive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this tutorial](http://www.dougv.com/2007/07/12/using-ajax-to-update-a-non-map-div-via-google-maps-apis-gdownload-and-gmarker-onclick-event/) which seems like it'll do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to load KML into a google maps application natively, there is actually a pretty good example of how this is done here:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/layers/layers.html

One trick I will mention is that since the KML is downloaded to Google's servers in order to be rendered on the map,  it must exist on a public facing web server somewhere,  Google won't be able to access it from your local machine.

Comment: One thing to watch  with the built in KML support, it doesnt give you easy access to individual features. There is some, but not much. Although it sounds like enough for this usecase, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlMouseEvent - when a user clicks on a point, can capture an event, with the details, which you can then render where you like. There are alternative KML parsers which make things easier, eg GeoXML3

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The GeoXML3 parser looks pretty useful for my purposes. All I'm really trying to do is build an external interface to present data (which might normally be found in the info window).  Therefore I want to suppress the info window, and capture the click event so that my "external sidebar" will display a bunch of information about that point...I have yet to find a good example of this.  I'm pretty new at javascript/google maps api so if anyone knows of an example that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!