# Google Maps API - Display marker info outside map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

When you click on the marker, the info that would normally show up in the bubble, is instead displayed in a DIV outside the map, in a section to the right, with it's own formatting.

I'm not really sure what to do. I tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713860/google-maps-api-marker-info-in-sidebar), but that was from 2007, and I think the GDownload() function is now deprecated. Or at least, I couldn't find any reference of it in the documentation and API lists on the Google Developer site.

All I know is that I need to convert the following into a DIV, somehow.

```
downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var locations = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var name = locations[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = locations[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = locations[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(locations[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(locations[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<div id=loc> <div class=loc-name>" + name + "</div> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + "<div class=loc-type>" + type + "</div></div>";
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon,
      shadow: icon.shadow
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }
});
}
 document.getElementById("loc-info").innerHTML = html;

 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infoWindow.setContent(html);
     infoWindow.open(map, marker);
   });
 }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the code that creates the infowindow to set the content of your div :

```
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     document.getElementById('loc-info').innerHTML = html;
   });
 }
```

**EDIT :** You also want to remove that line (the one before your `function bindInfoWindow`), which does nothing, since `html` doesn't exist at this point :

```
document.getElementById("loc-info").innerHTML = html;
```